# I want to delay a link for a period of 500 with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, time, hyperlink, delay

I've been looking through the Stackoverflow questions, trying to get help with a simple link delay; I want to put it around a div, and I can't make heads or tails of the examples I've found.

So far, I understand that I need to halt the native function of href, but I don't know how to do that. The code is still very alien to me. Help?

Comment: What do you mean by *"delay a link"*?

Comment: Do you mean a time delay that occurs when the user _clicks_ on a link before the browser navigates to the linked page?

Comment: Please be more specific in the question. Most of it doesn't make much sense. Some example or snippet will be helpful

Comment: Yes, mxgr, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set your `href` attribute as `href="javascript:delay('URL')"` and JavaScript:

```
function delay (URL) {
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 500 );
}
```

Comment: This is going to be a really dumb question, but where do I put this so that it affects a div?

Comment: Ohh, in case this is for a div, then make it <div onclick="delay ('www.google.com')">Click here to go to google in half a second</div>

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized what to do. Thanks.

Comment: This works great for me - quick question: Should the () in setTimeout function() have the URL as a parameter too though?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to delay every link on your page, you can do it with jQuery like this

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(evt){
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = link;
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: For this to work, you will need add evt.preventDefault(); in the beginning of your function.

Comment: This does not support `target="_blank"`, or any other `target` setting.

Answer (score 1):

To delay a link with inline javascript, just
set your `href` attribute as `href="javascript:setTimeout(()=>{window.location = 'URL' },500);"`.

When you replace the URL with your link, just make sure it is inside the `' '`.

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="javascript:setTimeout(()=>{window.location = '#About' },500);">
    About Me
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to keep the function waiting before continuing:

```
var wait_until = new Date().getTime() + 500;
while (new Date().getTime() < wait_until) {
    //Do nothing, wait
}
```