# Delaying Hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to delay a hyperlink by 3 seconds as CSS has the delay animation, I have some icons with animation on them, for a mobile user they cant hover over the icons, but they would be able to see the icon animation if i had a delay on the hyperlinks?
Is this possible?
Thanks All!

Comment: what you want to delay?

Comment: When you click one of my icons, lets say its hyperlinked to 'Facebook', id like the button to wait 3/5 seconds to show the user the animation for the Facebook Icon before it loads up the 'Facebook' page
I cant really find anything online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related post: [I want to delay a link for a period of 500 with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434604/i-want-to-delay-a-link-for-a-period-of-500-with-javascript)

In summary:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:delay('URL', 3000)"></a>
```

Javascript:

```
function delay (URL, ms) {
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, ms);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that is perfect! Couldn't find that topic!